# UIButton Circular Movement

Tags: animation, uibutton

I am new to ios dev just for 3 weeks, and i am countering a problem while developping an app for my friend's bar.
The problem is I have created an mutable array with 10 UIButtons with custom images and with on-screen-position undefined, because when the view is loaded, I'd like to chain these buttons like a round circle, and they are moveable and reacts with touching and finger movement events, like the rough draw below, plz give me some hit, Plz advice.

sorry, i cant post image to describe this accurately due to i m a new user(low reputation)

Thanks a lot for your time~  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you how to place the buttons but not sure about the idead to rotate with touch.

You can use the polar coordinate for placing the UIButtons.

Use this

x = x0 + R * cos(theta)

y = y0 + R * sin(theta)

here (x0,y0) is the center of the circle.
R id radius
and theta will decide the spacing between the UIButtons

Remember the x,y needed for setting the frame are top left corner of the button.

Just play around with the values of x0,y0,R and theta.

Hope it works

Comment: : ) thanks a lot for your hint, i m working on it and it should be working, now i am focusing on how to animate the buttons moving around the circular path~,haha~ cheers